# Accessing a proxy with the cached credenitals in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, credentials

Is there a way to get cached proxy credentials in Python? What I mean is in `C#` you can do this:

```
string proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(requests.RequestUri).ToString();
requests.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
requests.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false);
requests.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

That will grab cached credentials and allow you to run with the proxy. Is there something similar in Python? Or is there a way I run that `C#` code to grab the credentials in a Python script?

Comment: proxies suck to deal with in python in my experience ... there are too many variations on types of proxies and from what i can tell requests works with like 1 or 2 of those variations... (its entirely possible that this is based on my addimittedly poor understanding of the inner workings of proxies)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Well thanks for ruining my day lol. Is there a way I could execute a c# script to grab the information when requested for the proxy creds?

Comment: sure just make your c# script into a dll library (or even a program that just outputs the requested data to stdout) and interface directly with it ... (although this is also  non-trivial ...)